# sqlite reader is empty but values are correct

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

I have a database connectio, with a SqliteDataReader. The reader sees the database just fine, but it can't find the user in the database, eventhough I've checked that the username and password is correct.

C#

```
using (var command = new SQLiteCommand("select * from Player where Username=@username and Password=@password", con))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("username", username);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("password", password.GetHashCode());


        SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.Read())
        {
           var p = createObject(reader);
           setPlayer(p);
           reader.Close();
           return true;
        }
    }
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What do you expect `password.GetHashCode()` to do? It returns an `Int32` value.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis - I want to "hide" the user password when people looks in the database.

Answer (score 2):

Your password is a `string` right?

Try removing `GetHashCode()` and just use password. `GetHashCode()` will give you an `int`, not a `string`.

Comment: The password is saved as an `int` in the database.

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx: "You should never persist or use a hash code outside the application domain in which it was created"